# If two distinct members of the set $\{ 2, 4, 12, 14, 21, 28, 98 \}$ are randomly selected and multiplied...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If two distinct members of the set $\{ 2, 4, 12, 14, 21, 28, 98 \}$ are randomly selected and multiplied, what is the probability that the product is a multiple of 196? Express your answer as a common fraction.

Comment: I would literally list out all valid pairs, and divide it by the total number of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom72 = 21$ ways to choose the two elements, and the valid pairs are

$$\{2,98\}, \{4,98\}, \{12,98\}, \{14,28\}, \{14,98\}, \{21,28\}, \{28,98\}$$

These are $7$ of the $21$ pairs, so the probability for the product to be a multiple of $196$ is $\frac{7}{21}=\frac13$.

Answer (score 0):

so we need multiple of 196. then we list out the factors of 196=14*14=2*7*2*7.

so any product which has atleast these as its factors will be the required numbers.

So, now we select 98 and we may find that only by multiplying by 2 we get 196. so from taking 98 as one of our numbers the other required numbers to multiplied will be 2,4,12,14,28. that's 5 required pairs.

now from the prime factorisation we may take pairs as (21,28) and (14,28). these are other two pairs required.

now comes the final part, the total number of pairs that can be formed are ${7_{C_{2}}}$=21

and hence the probability will become $\frac{7}{21}$.

hence the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.  :)